# Removing Java checked exception while overriding interface method?

Tags: java, exception, interface, overriding

I am using Java 7 and came across something very interesting. While extending the java.lang.Appendable interface with an interface of my own, I am overriding each method explicitly for documentation purposes more than anything.

All three methods defined in java.lang.Appendable throws IOException which I thought my overriding methods would also have to declare. However, I ended up deleting the throws clause on one of the overridden methods and strangely enough the Java 7 compiler didn't complain about the missing declaration. So I went ahead and deleted the throws clause from the other two methods and again, no complaints from the compiler.

So why can I override a method in an interface and remove its throws clause? And when did this phenomenon become legal in Java?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be legal? Why should you have to falsely declare your method throws an exception you know it doesn't?

Comment: I was thinking if someone said Appendable a = new MyInterfaceImpl(); that when they said a.append("Foo"); their code would still have to try-catch IOException (which they would). But I guess it makes sense that if MyInterface does not throw IOException for an Appendable method then that's OK because the MyInterface implementation will never throw IOException. I was just surprised to see this work is all.  Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parent interface declares that the method *might* throw an exception. An implementation that does not throw the exception conforms to one that *might*. Your interface is declaring that implementations do not in fact throw exceptions, while still adhering to the contract of the parent interface.

Code that assigns your instances to an `Appendable` variable will have to catch the exception as defined, while code that treats your instances as your child interface will not have to.

Put simply:

```
interface Foo {
    void m() throws Exception;
}

interface Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    void m();
}

void test(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
    foo.m(); // must catch exception
    bar.m(); // no exception declared to be thrown, so don't need to catch
}
```

Note also that it's the type of the variable, not the object that's important:

```
Foo foo = new BarImpl();
foo.m(); // must catch exception
```

Comment: Awesome, this makes perfect sense. Thanks!